# The constructor Image(Object) is not visible JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, imageview

I'm trying to create a new picture taking the image from an Imageview, the code is this:

```
Image image= new Image(imgview.getImage());
```

When I try to do this I got this error "The constructor Image(Object) is not visible", and I don't understand why.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you wanted an Image reference, you could have just tried `Image image = imgview.getImage(); `

Answer (score 0):

I solve in this way,

```
ImageView v2 = new ImageView(imgview.getImage());
```

without create an other image, and it works.